# How to Pass Int into the Soap Request in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client

is it possible to Send int element into SOAP Request means is it possible to make SOAP request  which is containing int Soap Element. bcoz i need to pass one Integer Element For the Soap request in java but not getting how to do it.

Comment: SOAP communication is done via XML (or JSON). Everything in this case is a string, which gets interpreted as something like an integer only by the framework on the server.

Comment: @SiKing well you are right so the thing is that we can not pass that as int right na??

Comment: Yes. You pass, for example, `1`. In transport it will be a string. The framework on the server will try to convert that into an int, in your example. If you pass, for example, `a`, when the server tries to convert that into an int, it will error out.

Comment: ya that is right. when i tried to sent int that is giving error but that time but other plate from was accepting int only so i did ask now its solved problem was at service side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by putting the integer logic into Soap request, input syntax is:

```
${= (logic)}
${=(int)(Math.random()*10)} <- this logic will replaced the input City parameter with an integer 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
 <soap:Header />
<soap:Body>
  <web:GetWeather>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <web:CityName>${=(int)(Math.random()*10)}</web:CityName>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <web:CountryName>USA</web:CountryName>
  </web:GetWeather>
```

When the above request is run, there is an integer for the city tag.

```
<web:CityName>3</web:CityName>
```